# Using Openlayers 3 clicks mouse and pop-up Overlay.is not work

Tags: gis, openlayers

I use openlayers3 to display the map, now I want to click on the mouse pop-up a dialog box, but no matter how I modify the following code  can not pop-up window, please help check, thank every body. The following code is a bit long, but I really don't know where I was wrong, so I have to post it all. I'm sorry.

```
<pre><code>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>  
    <head>  
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">  
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">  
    <title>OpenLayers MapQuest Demo</title>  

        <style type="text/css">  
            html, body, #map{  
                padding:0;  
                margin:0;  
                height:100%;  
                width:100%;  
            }  
            .mouse-position-wrapper{
                width:300px; 
                height:29px; 
                color:#FF00FF; 
                position:absolute; 
                right:20px; 
                bottom:6px; 
                z-index:999;
              }
              .ol-rotate{
                right:40px;
              }
              .ol-scale-line {
                left:180px;
              }
              .ol-zoomslider{
                top:120px;
                left: 9px;
              }
              #map {
                clear: both;
                position: relative;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
              #main{
                  width: 1024px;
                  height: 380px;
              }
              .ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent
              {
              display:none;
              } 
              .div_options_background,.div_options
              {
                  position: absolute;
                  top: 5px;
                  left: 5px;
                  //padding: 3px 5px; 
                  border-radius: 5px 5px;
              }
              .div_options_background
              {
                  //background-color: #3385ff;
              }
              .scale-line {
                  position: absolute;
                  bottom:0px;
                  left:0px; 
                  z-index:1999;
                }
                .ol-scale-line {
                  position: relative;
                  bottom: 0px;
                  left: 0px;
                  z-index:1999;         
                }
                .ol-popup {
                    position: absolute;
                    background-color: white;
                    padding: 15px;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
                    bottom: 12px;
                    left: -50px;
                z-index:1999;
                  }

                  .ol-popup:after, .ol-popup:before {
                    top:0;// 100%;
                    border: solid transparent;
                    content: " ";
                    height: 0;
                    width: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    pointer-events: none;
                  z-index:1999;
                  }
                  .ol-popup:after {
                    border-top-color: white;
                    border-width: 10px;
                    left: 48px;
                    margin-left: -10px;
                  z-index:1999;
                  }
                  .ol-popup:before {
                    border-top-color: #cccccc;
                    border-width: 11px;
                    left: 48px;
                    margin-left: -11px;
                  z-index:1999;
                  }
                  .ol-popup-closer {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 2px;
                    right: 8px;
                  z-index:1999;
                  }
                  .ol-popup-closer:after {
                    content: "✖";
                  z-index:1999;
                  }
                  *popup code is end.
        </style>  
        <script src="/Scripts/js/jquery2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/commonjs/mf_urlOp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/ext4.2/ext-all.js"></script>
        <script src="/view/GIS/measure.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <link href="/Scripts/ext4.2/resources/ext-theme-classic/ext-theme-classic-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
            <script src="/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="/Scripts/js/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>   

        <!--
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8099/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="http://localhost:8099/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        -->

        <script src="/Scripts/js/ol.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Scripts/js/ol.css">
    </head>  
    <body >  
    <div id='main'>
    <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm
    <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
    <div id="popup-content" style="width:300px; height:120px;">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    </div>
        <div id="map" class="map">



     <div id="scale-line" class="scale-line"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div_options_background"></div>
    <div class="div_options" id="div_options" >
    模式:
    <select id="select_mode" style='font-size:12px;border-radius: 5px;'>
    <option value ="HaiYang_XiaoQuQuYu_WU">全部隐藏</option>
    <option value ="HaiYang_XiaoQuQuYu_YCWD" onclick="setStyle(layerImage_QuYu,'HaiYang_XiaoQuQuYu_YCWD');">一网温度</option>
    <option value="HaiYang_XiaoQuQuYu_YCYL">一网</option>
    <option value="audi">未完...</option>
    </select>

    &nbsp;测量:<select id="type" style="border-radius:5px">
    <option value="">无</option>
    <option value="length">线</option>
    <option value="area">面</option>
    </select>
    <ol id="measureOutput" style="margin:0;padding: 0;text-align: center;background-color: lightgreen;"></ol>
    </div>
    </div>
         <div id="label" style="display: none;">      
            <div id="marker" class="marker" title="Marker">
                <a class="address" id="address" target="_blank" href="http://www.openlayers.org/">标注点11111111111</a>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="location"></div>
            <div id="scale">
        </div>
        <div id="nodelist">
            <em>Click on the map to get feature info</em>
        </div>


       <script type="text/javascript">  
       var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
           className: 'custom-mouse-position',
           target: document.getElementById('location'),
           coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(5),
           undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
         });
        var projection =ol.proj.get("EPSG:3857");    

        var format = 'image/png';
        var bounds = [126.23673285210907, 30.151201961467336,
            140.6467487034272, 40.939360900441784];
        var projectionExtent =/*[-100,-90,100,90];*/ projection.getExtent();


        var size = ol.extent.getWidth(projectionExtent) / 256;
        var res = new Array(18);
        var matrixIds = new Array(18);
        for (var z = 1; z < 19; ++z) {
            res[z] = size / Math.pow(2, z);
            matrixIds[z] = z;
        }
        var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine();
        var layerImage_QuYu=  new ol.layer.Image({
                source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                    ratio: 1,
                    url: 'http://localhost:8099/geoserver/cite/wms',
                    params: {'FORMAT': format,
                             'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                          STYLES: 'HaiYang_XiaoQuQuYu_WU',
                          "exceptions": 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
                          "LAYERS": 'cite:View_HaiYangXiaoQu',
                    }
                  })
                });

        var map = new ol.Map({
           controls:ol.control.defaults().extend([mousePositionControl]),
          layers: [

            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.WMTS({
                name: "中国矢量1-4级",
                url: "http://t0.tianditu.com/vec_w/wmts?tk=70ef04fe6a1cedea7cd7523dfd7816ff",
                layer: "vec",
                style: "default",
                matrixSet: "w",
                format: "tiles",
                wrapX: true,
                projection: projection,
                tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                  origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
                  resolutions: res,
                  matrixIds: matrixIds,//[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
                })
              }),
            }),

            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.WMTS({
                name: "中国矢量注记1-4级",
                //url: "http://t7.tianditu.gov.cn/cva_c/wmts?tk=70ef04fe6a1cedea7cd7523dfd7816ff",
                url: "http://t{0-7}.tianditu.gov.cn/cva_w/wmts?tk=70ef04fe6a1cedea7cd7523dfd7816ff",
                layer: "cva",
                style: "default",
                //matrixSet: "c",
                matrixSet: "w",
                format: "tiles",
                wrapX: true,
                projection: projection,
                tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                  origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent),
                  resolutions: res,
                  matrixIds:matrixIds,// [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
                })
              }),
            }), 
            layerImage_QuYu,
                new ol.layer.Image({
                    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
                      ratio: 1,
                      url: 'http://localhost:8099/geoserver/cite/wms',
                      params: {'FORMAT': format,
                               'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
                            STYLES: '',
                            LAYERS: 'cite:SSql_GuanDao',
                      }
                    })
                  }),
                  new ol.layer.Tile({
                    visible: false,
                    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                      url: 'http://localhost:8099/geoserver/cite/wms',
                      params: {'FORMAT': format, 
                               'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                               tiled: true,
                            STYLES: '',
                            LAYERS: 'cite:SSql_GuanDao',
                      }
                    })
                  }),
          ],
          target: "map",
          controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
              new ol.control.ScaleLine({className: 'ol-scale-line', target: document.getElementById('scale-line')}),
              mousePositionControl,
            ]),
          view: new ol.View({
              projection: projection,
              center: [13486339.06881, 4406575.57138],
              zoom: 4
          })
        });

        //单击事件
        map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
            var typeSelect=document.getElementById('type');
            if(typeSelect.value!="")
            {
                return;
            }
            var view = map.getView();
            var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
            var source = layerImage_QuYu.get('visible') ? layerImage_QuYu.getSource() : layerTile_QuYu.getSource();
            var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
              evt.coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
              {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50});
            if (url) {
                if(mf_urlOp.getParam(url,"QUERY_LAYERS")=="cite%3AView_HaiYangXiaoQu"
                        ||mf_urlOp.getParam(url,"QUERY_LAYERS")=="cite:View_HaiYangXiaoQu")
                {
                    console.log(url);
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'jsonWebGIS_getInfo', 
                        data:{'url':url},
                        type: "post", //规定请求的类型（GET 或 POST）。
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(data) {  //请求成功后返回
                            console.log(data);
                            alert(data[0].ECHW);
                        },
                        error: function() {  //请求失败后返回
                            //alert(234);
                            console.log('Request Error.');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
          });

          map.getView().setCenter([13486339.06881, 4406575.57138]);
          map.getView().setZoom(15); 

          function setStyle(sourceLayer,style)
          {
              var v1=sourceLayer.getSource();
              var v2=v1.getParams();
              v2.STYLES=style;
              v1.changed();
          }

          init();

          /**
           * Elements that make up the popup.
           */
          var container = document.getElementById('popup');
          var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
          var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');


          /**
           * Add a click handler to hide the popup.
           * @return {boolean} Don't follow the href.
           */
          closer.onclick = function() {
            overlay.setPosition(undefined);
            closer.blur();
            return false;
          };

          /**
           * Create an overlay to anchor the popup to the map.
           */
          var overlay = new ol.Overlay(/** @type {olx.OverlayOptions} */ ({
            element: container,
            autoPan: true,
            autoPanAnimation: {
              duration: 250   //当Popup超出地图边界时，为了Popup全部可见，地图移动的速度. 单位为毫秒（ms）
            }
          }));

            //overlay.setPosition([13486339.06881, 4406575.57138]);    

          /**
           * Add a click handler to the map to render the popup.
           */
          map.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
            var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
            var hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(
                coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));
            content.innerHTML = '<p>你点击的坐标是：</p><code>' + hdms + '</code>';

            container.style.height = "100px;"
                content.style.overflowY = "scroll";
            content.style.height = "90px";
            content.style.width = "100px";

            overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
            map.addOverlay(overlay);
          });
    </script>  
    </body>
    </html>
</code></pre>
```

Comment: If you change `map.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {` to `map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {` you should see a popup appear.  But to display meaningful information you would need to display the popup in the success function of your ajax call.

Comment: very thx!this is.